# How to show different data through one API in django-rest?

Tags: api, django-rest-framework, django-views

#serializer.py file

```
class StorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields = ("id",
            "title",
            "featured",
             summary",)
```

#views.py file

```
class StoryList(BaseListAPIView):
    serializer_class = StorySerializer
    model = Story
```

#url

```
url(r"^stories/org/", StoryList.as_view(), name="api.v1.org_story_list"),
```

when i will call api suppose api.v1.org_story_list then show all fields data id,title,fetured,summary.
but when I will call same api but add extra parameter like that api.v1.org_story_list/addd
then show specific field like that id,title,summary.
featured field will not called.

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can update your views and make custom list api view like this following code:

```
 def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = UserSerializer(request.user).data
        if data=="xxxx":
            organizations = OrganizationUser.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).values('organization')
            data['organization_profiles'] = OrganizationProfileListSerializer(
                OrganizationProfile.objects.all(), many=True).data
        else: 
            data['organization_profiles'] = OrganizationProfileIndividualSerializer(
            OrganizationProfile.objects.get(user=request.user )).data

        return Response(data=data)
```

Here different serializer is being used based on condition.

Comment: i need when call api with extra parameter then featured will not called.
not hide. Just api returns id,titleand summary field except featured field

Comment: You can override the post/get method and use serializer based on your need. Based on your parameters you need to select serializers.

Comment: How to do it can give me code example?

Comment: Answer updated.